# PHP - how to print each row of an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I feel like I'm missing something really simple here. Here's my sql query:

```
$getpages = "SELECT id FROM pages WHERE account = 2 ORDER BY page_order";       
$showpages = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $getpages);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($showpages, MYSQLI_NUM);
```

I then print the first result:

```
echo $row[0];
```

And get a correct value, the id of the first page (by page order):

10

So I submit a form which simply turns that `$row[0]` into `$row[1]`.

And nothing prints. I don't understand.

Comment: Please post more code not enough to go on. Where and what are you trying to print and how is your form set up?

Comment: "So I submit a form which simply turns that $row[0] into $row[1]." <- can you show this part?

Comment: See the FAQ on Why does my `mysql_fetch_array` only return one row http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info

Comment: Which form? Can you show the code of that form?

Comment: To get multiple rows you must fetch them in a loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array return only one row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001320/mysql-fetch-array-return-only-one-row)

Comment: @Michael NO, he is not asking about showing multiple rows just posting to get the next row

Comment: @LaurenceBurke Only one column is specified in the SELECT list. I interpret that as a misunderstanding of how `mysql_fetch_array()` works, assuming that it returns all results.

Comment: You should indeed post the code of the form you're talking about in order to see more clearly the source of the problem.

Comment: @Michael - I think you're right in that the problem may be with how my SELECT query and the mysql_fetch_array are working together... but what's the alternative?

Comment: The form just changes the 0 to a 1. I can do it manually without the form and get the same results. I don't think that's it.

Comment: @JasonHerndon If you only want one row, use `LIMIT $n, 1` where `$n` is the record you need, then fetch and access as `$row[0]`

Comment: @JasonHerndon although I'm no longer 100% sure what your problem is have you tried using the query mentions below? with the * rather than "SELECT id"? Because your $row[1] will be blank as only one column is returned in your query.

Comment: @Michael - that's it! By limiting the query and updating the $n variable I can do this. Would love to give you the right answer on this! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Using this method you will fire a query for every row you want. If you want all the rows where account = 2 then use one of the loops below, If you want just one and you know which one use the method @Michael said.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($showpages, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    $id = $row[id];
    // do something with the id
    echo $id . "<br/>"; // Echo every id
}
```

This will iterate through all of the results

Comment: No not the answer the OP is looking for please reread the question.

Comment: Are you sure? I think that's pretty much what he's asking for, although "so I submit a form which simply turns that `$row[0]` into `$row[1]`" is incomprehensible.

Comment: Similar problem though. When I substitute $row[0] for $row[id] I get all the values in the array and when I use $row[1] I get nothing

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when you write `$row[1]`? `$row[1]` will return the second column of your result, but you're only selecting one, `id`.

Comment: I was expecting the next ID from the SQL query

Comment: Do as I've explained, use a `while` loop to get the next `$row`. Every time you call `mysqli_fetch_array` you get **one** row (i.e. one id), so you need to keep calling that function to get the next row (i.e. the next id). @LaurenceBurke please vote my answer up :P

Comment: No problem as long as the OP understands that this will not submit to a post refresh

Comment: And that's what I needed it to do :)

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_fetch_array is a special function as each time you call it, it outputs the NEXT row.

So:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array(stuff)){
    $var = $row['sql column'];
    // In your case "$var = $row[0];" to get the id for the first row found.
}
```

is how you use it.

This will keep running the function until mysqli_fetch_array() eventually returns false. These each time it will output a new row. And the $row array is the array of one row in the sql table.

Use :

```
print_r($row);
```

in the while loop to see exactly what's being returned for use.

Comment: No he is not asking about showing all the rows in the page. He is post refreshing. Please read the question fully.

Comment: Ah... removing my answer then.

Comment: Brought this back as I think this is actually what he was asking for

Answer (score 0):

```
$getpages = "SELECT id FROM pages WHERE account = 2 ORDER BY page_order";       
$showpages = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $getpages);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($showpages, MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Question how many rows are fetched in this query in this case id, So MYSQL will result to 1 row affected, But since you are using

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($showpages, MYSQLI_NUM);
```

This code you used will not output anything try

```
$row[n]  as n-1
```

Answer (score -1):

`$result->fetch_assoc()` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)`
catch one line at a time, from a mysqli_result:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

source: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp