# MySQL - moving to next result using mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array return only one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001320/mysql-fetch-array-return-only-one-row)

Let's say I use mysql_fetch_assoc, to filter things like:

```
mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * from tickets WHERE issuer = '" . $name . "'"));
```

I usually just use a for loop to loop between tickets by using ticketid column (auto increamenting) however, when I use this one, I might have ticketid 1 and then ticketid 4, since I'm filtering it by the issuer. Any way to get the ticketid of the next result or just get the fetched value of it?

Comment: Never nest `mysql_query()` inside `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.  Instead, use a `while` loop.  There are many many examples to be found here.  There [is an example loop on the PHP tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info). The pattern is: store the query result resource in a variable, test it for success, then loop over it to fetch rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysql_query return an resource, you should using mysql_fetch_assoc each it, so try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from tickets WHERE issuer = '" . $name . "'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

And more [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Maybe you can try [PHP Data Objects (PDO)](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php)