# Resource id #2 query mysql php

Tags: database, html

I tried with many things and it always said the same i need return the user or the list of all users 
i dont know what happen, 
resul returns Resource id and
if i print mysql_fetch_array it returns Array and print r doesnt return all users in my database

```
<?php 

            ,
            $consulta = "SELECT user FROM usuarios";

             $resul = mysql_query($consulta,$conexion);
                echo $resul;


              print_r(mysql_fetch_array($resul));


            ?>
```

with phpmyadmin return all users.. that query works fine when i put that with phpmyadmin 
i have in that moment in the database one table called usuarios with 3 columns called user(admin,pablo) pass(admin,pablo) and obviously id

but the ouput is this

```
Resource id #2Array ( [0] => admin [user] => admin )
```

Comment: [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) only returns one row at a time. You might try fetching in a loop: `while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($resul)) { print_r($row); }`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array return only one row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001320/mysql-fetch-array-return-only-one-row)